# "'int' object has no attribute 'save'" Update models from views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to update user model in a views.py. Is there a way to do that? What I want to do is minus user point in views.py and update into models without a form. but it gave me " 'int' object has no attribute 'save'"

views.py

```
    def buy_item(request, item_name):
        item = ShopItem.objects.get(item_name=item_name)
        price = item.item_price
        user = request.user
        user_point = user.point
        if user_point >= price:
            user_point = user_point - price
            point_left = user_point
            point_left.save()
            msg = messages.success(request, 'You bought item!')
            return redirect('/shop', msg)
        else:
            msg = messages.success(request, 'You do not have enough point')

        context = ({
            'point': user_point,
            'item': item,
            'form': form
        })

        return render(request, 'item.html', context)
```

item models.py

```
class ShopItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media_items')
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_command = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

    def snippet(self):
        return self.item_description[:45]
```

user models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default='', unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

What I want is to save the point after changed.

What should I do? Please help! I'm really new to this. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, but you need to use [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method in a model, not in an Integer.

So, you should replace

```
point_left = user_point
point_left.save()
```

for this

```
user.point = user_point # Assign the new point to the user
user.save() # Update your user model
```